# PHP string manipulation, inside the string

Tags: php, string

I have string:

```
ABCDEFGHIJK
```

And I have two arrays of positions in that string that I want to insert different things to.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 5
)

Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 9
)
```

Which if I decided to add the `#` character and the `=` character, it'd produce:

```
#ABCDE=FG#HI=JK
```

Is there any way I can do this without a complicated set of `substr`?

Also, `#` and `=` need to be variables that can be of any length, not just one character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string as array

```
$str = "ABCDEFGH";
$characters = preg_split('//', $str, -1);
```

And afterwards you [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to insert '#' or '=' to position given by array
Return the array back to string is done by:

```
$str = implode("",$str);
```

Comment: You have to be careful with `array_splice`. E.g. after insertion of the first two characters, index `7` does not point to `G` anymore, but to `F`. How would you solve this?

Comment: Yes, you have to have some iteration index and in every `array_splice` add this index to wanted position. Just control it by if..else based on max(insertion_index) where insertion_index is based on already made insertions. (just hope i haven't twisted in words :D)

Answer (score 0):

This works for any number of characters (I am using "#a" and "=b" as the character sequences):

```
function array_insert($array,$pos,$val)
{
    $array2 = array_splice($array,$pos);
    $array[] = $val;
    $array = array_merge($array,$array2);

    return $array;
}
$s = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
$arr = str_split($s);
$arr_add1 = array(0=>0, 1=>5);
$arr_add2 = array(0=>7, 1=>9);
$char1 = '#a';
$char2 = '=b';
$arr = array_insert($arr, $arr_add1[0], $char1);
$arr = array_insert($arr, $arr_add1[1] + strlen($char1), $char2);
$arr = array_insert($arr, $arr_add2[0]+ strlen($char1)+ strlen($char2), $char1);
$arr = array_insert($arr, $arr_add2[1]+ strlen($char1)+ strlen($char2) + strlen($char1), $char2);
$s = implode("", $arr);
print_r($s);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy function for that: [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php). But for this to work, you would have to structure you array differently (which would be more structured anyway), e.g.:

```
$replacement = array(
    0 => '#', 
    5 => '=', 
    7 => '#', 
    9 => '='
);
```

Then sort the array by keys descending, using [`krsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php):

```
krsort($replacement);
```

And then you just need to loop over the array:

```
$str = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

foreach($replacement as $position => $rep) {
    $str = substr_replace($str, $rep, $position, 0);
}

echo $str; // prints #ABCDE=FG#HI=JK
```

This works by inserting the replacements starting from the end of string. And it would work with any replacement string without having to determine the length of that string.

Working [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/9rOYS730)